# how to use one DatePickerDialog in two classes?

Tags: android, android-layout, datepickerdialog

I have class `MyClass1`, that use `DatePickerDialog`.

```
    public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        /* implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener */ {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (MyClass1)getActivity(), MyClass1.year, MyClass1.month, MyClass1.day);
    }

}
```

Now I want to use the same `DatePickerDialog` in class `MyClass2`. 
What I have to use instead of `"(MyClass1)getActivity()"` to get working `DatePickerDialog` with both classes?

Comment: create a separate class of datepicker, create instance of the datepicker in your respective classes and use them

Comment: Try this lib for Global access.[Link](https://github.com/CommonUtils/android).

Answer (score 0):

You can either make another class where you can create DialogFragment and called in both classes by

```
DatePickerFragment dialog=new DatePickerFragment();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),null);
```

Comment: it is not an answer.

Comment: I have to use "(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener)getActivity()" instead of "(MyClass1)getActivity()"